# dbms_alert Интервалы опроса

Tags: oracle, plsql, события

Объясните, пожалуйста, вот этот абзац из документации

> `WAITANY` procedure. If you use the `WAITANY` procedure, and if a signalling session does a signal but does not commit within one second of the signal, a polling loop is required so that this uncommitted alert does not camouflage other alerts. The polling loop begins at a one second interval and exponentially backs off to 30-second intervals.

Я правильно понимаю, что тут говорится о том, что при вызове `WAITANY` на сервере поток опрашивает наличие событий, через определенные интервалы? И если я вызвал `WAITANY` с достаточно большим таймаутом, то при возникновении события ко мне придет уведомление только после истечения текущего интервала запроса? Т.е. на сервере выполняется примерно такой код

```
function WaitAny(ATimeout) {
  const intervals = [0, 1, ....., 30);
  for (i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++) {
    Sleep(min(intervals[i], ATimeout))
    if (IsExistsEvents())
      return 0;
    ATimeout -= intervals[i];
    if (ATimeout <= 0)
      return 1;
  }
  maxInterval = intervals[intervals.length - 1];
  while (ATimeout > 0) {
    Sleep(min(maxInterval, ATimeout))
    if (IsExistsEvents())
      return 0;
    ATimeout -= maxInterval;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Не совсем так. О таймауте для WAITANY здесь речи не идёт. Здесь говорится, как часто будет смена между ожиданем ещё не полученных сигналов и ожиданием уже полученных, но не закомиченных сигналов. Т.к. хорошая практика посылать сигналы непосредственно перед коммитом, то у вас эта ситуация практически не должна возникнуть и сигналы обработаются почти мгновенно.  Например, если у вас длинная трансакция, которая может выполнятся в нескольких сессиях паралельно, то посылать сигнал из триггера в самом её начале, не совсем удачное решение.

Comment: @0xdb Вы бы не могли расшифровать свои утверждения ` хорошая практика посылать сигналы непосредственно перед коммитом` и `посылать сигнал из триггера в самом её начале, не совсем удачное решение`? Почему?

Comment: Это только как пример, что не желательно так делать, а посылать сигнал в конце трансакции, и в конечном итоге избежать pooling в приёмнике сигнала. Если опять не понятно,  спрашивайте.

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47364760/dbms-alert-polling-intervals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Нет, при получении события, оповещение о нём будет практически сразу же передано в обработчик, то есть возврат из функции `waitany`. Но в определённых случаях задержка возможна (см. далее).

---

Передача события (*signal*) между отправителем и приёмником в `dbms_alert` транзакциональна и состоит из двух частей:

1. Не транзакциональная передача события посредством *database pipe* механизма (реализовано на `dbms_pipe`).
2. Подтверждение события посредством `commit` в отправителе. В приёмнике это реализовано стандартным *lock* меанизмом БД.

В нормальном случае, приёмник ждёт получение события из *pipe*. При его получении, оно только регистрируется как принятое, но не подтверждённое. При наличии таких событий в приёмнике, `waitany` опрашивает статус сессии на предмет завершения транзакции, в которой событие было послано.
Если транзакция завершается с `commit`, то waitany завершается и передаёт текущее событие в приёмник для дальнейшей обработки, в противном случае - `rollback` - событие удаляется из очереди принятых в `waitany`.

В исключительном, случае, о котором идёт речь в цитате из вопроса, событие ещё не зафиксировано. т.е. не подтверждено в сессии отправителя. Так как бесконечное ожидание на подтверждение будет блокировать получение других событий из *pipe*, начинается опрос с интервалом начиная с 1-ой с возрастанием до 30-ти секунд. То есть приёмник ожидает подтверждения завершения транзакции с текущим интервалом ожидания (1..30 сек.) и если оно не происходит, возвращается к считыванию из *pipe* новых событий, после чего цикл повторяется.

Почему последний случай исключительный? Если событие отправленно, но не зафиксировано сразу же, то это, как будет видно в примере ниже, не обеспечит гарантированной асинхронной обработки событий. Поэтому, или устранить задержку между `signal` и `commit`, или, если это не представляется возможным, отказаться от `dbms_alert` и посмотреть в сторону [*Advanced gueuing*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adque/index.html) (`dbms_aq`).

Пример для наглядности. Понадобится три сесси: приёмнк, "ленивый" отправитель (PROCL=lazy SID=26) и "правильный" отправитель (PROCQ=quick SID=270).

Запустим приёмник событий:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on size unlimited
exec dbms_alert.register ('PROCQ'); -
     dbms_alert.register ('PROCL'); -
     dbms_alert.register ('EXIT');
exec receiveSignals
```

В отправителе SID=26 пошлём событие с задержкой подтверждения:

```
SQL> exec sendSignal ('PROCL',delayed=>true)
PROCL sent 14:02:10.482 from 26 delayed
```

В отправителе SID=270 пошлём событие и зафиксируем его сразу:

```
SQL> exec sendSignal ('PROCQ',delayed=>false)
PROCQ sent 14:03:20.842 from 270
```

Вернёмся в SID=26 и подтвердим событие:

```
SQL> exec sendSignal (null,delayed=>false)
none sent 14:03:34.272 from 26
```

В отправителе SID=270 пошлём событие EXIT:

```
SQL> exec sendSignal ('EXIT',delayed=>false)
EXIT sent 14:03:41.849 from 270
```

Вывод в приёмнике после приёма события EXIT:

```
stat=0,sig=PROCL,received=14:03:34.274: msg=sent 14:02:10.482 from 26 delayed
stat=0,sig=PROCQ,received=14:03:34.275: msg=sent 14:03:20.842 from 270
stat=0,sig=EXIT,received=14:03:41.852: msg=sent 14:03:41.849 from 270
```

Видно, что задержка в SID=26 вызвана поздним подтверждением и была получена в приёмнике сразу же после `commit` в отправителе (`14:03:34`). Но ожидание на подтверждение привело к задержке почти 15 сек на получения события от SID=270. (отпр. `14:03:20`, получ. `14:03:34`), т.е функция `waitany` в момент отправки подтверждённого события от SID=270, находилась в ожидании подтверждения от SID=26.

---

PS: Этот ответ не является переводом, ни прямым, ни вольным, ответа сотрудника компании *Oracle* на аналогичный [вопрос ТС на engl. SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47364760/dbms-alert-polling-intervals), он скорее всего попытка более наглядного пояснения ситуации.

Функции, которые использованы в воиспроизводимом примере выше:

```
create or replace procedure receiveSignals is
    sig varchar2 (32);
    stat number;
    msg varchar2 (64);
begin
    loop
        dbms_alert.waitany (sig, msg, stat);
        dbms_output.put_line (
            'stat='||stat||',sig='||sig||',received='||to_char (systimestamp, 'hh24:mi:ss.ff3')||': msg='||msg);
        exit when sig = 'EXIT';
    end loop;
end;
/
create or replace procedure sendSignal (sig varchar2, delayed boolean := true) is
    msg varchar2 (1800) := 'sent '||to_char (systimestamp, 'hh24:mi:ss.ff3')||' from '||
        sys_context ('USERENV', 'SID')||case when delayed then ' delayed' end; 
begin
    if sig is not null then dbms_alert.signal (sig, msg); end if;
    if not delayed then commit; end if;
    dbms_output.put_line (case when sig is null then 'none' else sig end||' '||msg);  
end;
/
```